# how to check packet type is tcp syn or rst in pox controller

Tags: python, python-2.7, sdn, pox

Here is the code

```
import pox.lib.packet as pkt
from pox.lib.packet import *
def _handle_PacketIn(self,event):
  packet=event.parsed
  if packet.type == pkt.IP_TYPE:
    ip_packet = packet.payload
    if ip_packet.protocol == pkt.TCP_PROTOCOL:
      tcp_packet = ip_packet.payload
    if <condition to check packet is TCP SYN or ACK or RST>:
```

1. what shoud be the expression within if to check whether that TCP packet is SYN/ACK/RST?

Answer (score 1):

In order to find SYN , ACK etc you have to use the packet.find method. 
The following is just a small modification at the forwarding.l2_pairs stock component of POX (carp)

Let's say we have mininet up and running

```
sudo mn --controller remote
```

Add a couple of lines of code at the stock component [forwarding.l2_pairs](https://github.com/CPqD/RouteFlow/blob/master/pox/pox/forwarding/l2_pairs.py) at line 41 after packet = event.parsed we will modify like so

```
packet = event.parsed
tcp_found = packet.find('tcp')
if tcp_found:
  if tcp_found.SYN:
    print "SYN found"
```

Run in a different terminal than mininet the pox component like so

```
python pox.py forwarding.l2_pairs host_tracker openflow.discovery
```

Now, in order to get some SYN flags let's go in the mininet terminal and setup a default python http server

```
h1 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &
```

and get the contents of the dummy server from host 2

```
h2 wget -O - h1
```

at the terminal that we run the pox l2_pairs component we examine the output

```
INFO:forwarding.l2_pairs:Pair-Learning switch running.
INFO:host_tracker:host_tracker ready
INFO:core:POX 0.2.0 (carp) is up.
INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-01 1] connected
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 2 6e:6e:ca:c9:2b:93
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 2 6e:6e:ca:c9:2b:93 got IP 10.0.0.2
SYN found
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 1 52:3b:b2:ff:ff:b7
INFO:host_tracker:Learned 1 1 52:3b:b2:ff:ff:b7 got IP 10.0.0.1
SYN found
```

The catch here is that as stated in the POX documentation SYN, ACK etc are tcp attributes

> TCP (tcp) 
>   Attributes: ...... 
>   FIN (bool) - True when FIN flag set 
>   SYN (bool) - True when SYN flag set 
>   ......

To get those attributes we assign the tcp part of the packet to a variable using the find method, then we access the attributes using a dot (.) ex.

```
variable.attribute
```

and we are good to go (if found).